# AVR 8 bit timer - what to do when compare value doesn't fit in register?

Tags: c, timer, avr, atmega

Recently, I started programming the Atmega328P in pure c/c++, without all the arduino libraries and arduino IDE. I want to blink an LED at a rate of 1Hz (1 sec. on, 1 sec. off). Unfortunately, I can only use Timer0, an 8-bit timer. The mcu has a clock frequency of 16MHz and I chose a prescaler of 1024 to reduce to number of overflows as much as possible to reduce jitter, as an interrupt routine always has overhead (this makes more sense if you read the rest of my question). Using simple maths, I came to conclusion that after 1 second, `Timer0` has overflowed 61 times and that the `TCNT0` register equals 8.

Then, I came up with this solution:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000ul

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define bit(b) (1 << (b))

void initBlinkTimer()
{
    //Timer0 with CTC Mode
    TCCR0A |= bit(WGM01) | bit(WGM00);

    //Compare TCNT0 with 8
    OCR0B = 8;

    //Interrupt at OCR0B compare match aka: execute interrupt when TCNT0 equals 8
    TIMSK0 |= bit(OCIE0B);

    //Set PB5 as output
    DDRB |= bit(PB5);

    //Set the prescaler to 1024
    TCCR0B |= bit(CS02) | bit(CS00);

    //Enable global interrupts, so that the interrupt routine can be executed upon the OCR0B compare match
    sei();
}

//Keeps track of the number of overflows
volatile unsigned char nOverflows = 0;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
{
    if(nOverflows >= 61)
    {
        //Toggle PB5
        PORTB ^= bit(PB5);

        //Reset timer
        nOverflows = 0;
        TCNT0 = 0;
    }
    else
    {       
        nOverflows++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    initBlinkTimer();
    while(1){}
}
```

This code initializes an 8-bit CTC timer with a prescaler of 1024. An interrupt service routine (ISR) is executed when TCNT0 equals OCR0B, which I set to 8 in my code. In the ISR, the `nOverflows` variable is compared to 61. If `nOverflows` equals 61, one second has passed and the PB5 pin is to be toggled. It also performs a greater-than check, in case the mcu missed the 61th overflow (if that's somehow possible in this case). The timer and `nOverflows` variable are cleared after toggling the pin and the timer then starts again from zero.

My question is: Is this a good way to blink an LED at 1Hz, when only an 8-bit timer is available? Can/should a part of this be implemented in the hardware instead of in the software?

Comment: It's as good a way as any....

Comment: If a timer does not have a long enough time span, configure it so that it interrupts at an exact fraction of the required time, and increments a static counter so that when it reaches the required time, you invert the LED state, and reset the counter.

Comment: @user7353781 I thought my answer was pretty comprehensive, so please consider clicking the check mark to accept it.

Comment: Is the code supposed to blink the LED. It's not working in mine?I am having trouble working with "Output Compare B Match Interrupt", I was searching google for resolve it and came across this post. It's the only one I could find so far that uses  ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect).

Comment: CTC mode doesn't work with OCR0B, only with OCR0A

Answer (score 1):

You don't need super high precision in your LED blinking; no one will be able to tell with their eyes if it is slightly off.

I'd say you should configure the timer to overflow about one to ten times per millisecond.  Let's say it overflows every 251 microseconds (the exact number doesn't matter).  Then every time it overflows, you add 251 to a `uint16_t` variable for counting microseconds.  If the microsecond counter is greater than or equal to 1000, you subtract 1000 from it and increment your millisecond counter, which should probably be a `uint32_t` so you can use it to time long periods of time.

But what if the overflow period is not an exact number of microseconds?  That's still fine, because it will probably be expressible in the form "N/M milliseconds", where N and M are whole numbers.  So every time the overflow happens, you increment your counter by N.  If the counter reaches M, you subtract M from the counter and add 1 to your millisecond counter.  (In the preivous paragraph, we only considered the M=1000 case, and I think by starting with that case it is easier to see what I'm talking about.)

You can either use an ISR to update your millisecond counter or do it in your main-line code by frequently checking for an overflow flag.  Either way would work.

So now you have a variable that counts up once per millisecond, like the Arduino `millis()` function, and you can use it for all sorts of millisecond-scale timing, including blinking LEDs.

The least-significant bit (bit 0) of the millisecond counter toggles once per millisecond, so its period is 2 ms.  The next bit up from that (bit 1) has a period of 4 ms.  Bit 10 has a period of 2048 ms.

So a simple way to blink your LED with a period of 2048 ms would be:

```
led_state = millisecond_counter >> 10 & 1;
```

(The code above uses bitwise operations to set `led_state` to be a copy of bit 10 from the millisecond counter.  Assuming you run this code frequently and write `led_state` out to the LED using the I/O registers, your LED would then have a period of 2048 ms.)

If you really care that your LED is slow by 2.4%, you could do something more complicated like this:

```
static uint16_t last_toggle = 0;
if ((uint16_t)(millisecond_counter - last_toggle) >= 1000)
{
  last_toggle += 1000;
  toggle_the_led();
}
```